# MySQL-workbench 8 and escaping characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused on how to escape characters in MySQL-workbench 8.0?

1) Is it always the case that I should use double backslash to escape characters?

2) What are the characters that I should escape? For example, I am struggling to find out whether I should escape forward slashes or not.

Example:

```
select name
from nameTable
where regexp 'https?:\\/\\/.*'
```

OR

```
select name
from nameTable
where regexp 'https?:\/\/.*'
```

OR

```
select name
from nameTable
where regexp 'https?://.*'
```

**EDIT:**

The MySQL engine version is: `8.0.16`

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a visual database design tool that is developed by MySQL. the escaping is defined by the db engine (mysql) and not by the tool to access it

Comment: Plz check my edit if you have any idea so I know which method to use